# How to generate bitcoin target from difficulty?

Tags: difficulty, java

Reading the slushpool's manual for the Stratum protocol I found that :

*"Default share difficulty is 1 (big-endian target for difficulty 1 is **0x00000000ffff0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000**)"*

Anyone knows how to generate this 64characters long big-endian representation of the number 1 ? I would appreciate any code in Java.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't know Java, but the target is worked out as follows:

```
target = maximum target / difficulty
```

---

> Note: The **maximum target** is `0x00000000FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` (which in decimal is `26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960`)

Therefore:

```
target = maximum target / difficulty
target = 26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960 / 1
target = 26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960
```

So if you convert that back to hex you get:

```
0xFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Then you can just pad zeros on the left to make it 64 characters:

```
0x00000000FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

---

http://learnmeabitcoin.com/manual/guide/difficulty#finding-the-target-using-the-difficulty

Comment: Thank you for your information. I read more about the Stratum protocol and I found that the current network difficulty is stored in the nBits variable.

Comment: So now I have to figure out how I can convert the nBits to Target.